# Why npm run serve gives error on WSL with vue-cli?

Tags: npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vue-cli

When I run  `npm run serve` for my vue.js app on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), I have this error:

```
> todoapp_vue@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                 3:42:04 PM

These dependencies were not found:

* vue in ./src/main.js, ./src/router/index.js
* vue-router in ./src/router/index.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save vue vue-router
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/mnt/c/Documents and Settings'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/mnt/c/Documents and Settings'
```

If I try to run the same command on windows command line, I have the following error:

```
> todoapp_vue@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                              12:37:49

These dependencies were not found:

* vue in ./src/main.js, ./src/router/index.js
* vue-router in ./src/router/index.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save vue vue-router
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

When I run the suggested command `npm install --save vue vue-router`, here is the error message I get (it's the beginning of it only because it's too long for SO):

```
715 error code 1
716 error path /mnt/c/Users/Nobu/Desktop/DRF_Tutos/DRF_Vue_tuto/Vue_todoapp/todoapp_vue/node_modules/node-sass
717 error command failed
718 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
719 error Building: /home/Nobu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.2/bin/node /mnt/c/Users/Nobu/Desktop/DRF_Tutos/DRF_Vue_tuto/Vue_todoapp/todoapp_vue/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
719 error make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/Nobu/Desktop/DRF_Tutos/DRF_Vue_tuto/Vue_todoapp/todoapp_vue/node_modules/node-sass/build'
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o ../src/libsass/src/bind.cpp
719 error   cc '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o ../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o ../src/libsass/src/color_maps.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o ../src/libsass/src/constants.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o ../src/libsass/src/context.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o ../src/libsass/src/cssize.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o ../src/libsass/src/emitter.cpp
719 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/include/node -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/src -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/zlib -I/home/Nobu/.node-gyp/16.6.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o ../src/libsass/src/environment.cpp
```

Any idea of what could be the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Just checking, since you don't mention it -- What happened when you ran `npm install --save vue vue-router` as recommended by the error messages?

Comment: Good point @NotTheDr01ds, I'm going to edit my question to add the error message I get when I run this suggested command.

Comment: Finally I cannot add the error message because it's too long

Comment: Is the entire result an error, or does it work for some portion and then error out?  At least look for the beginning of the error output and try to get the first few lines.  If it is scrolling beyond the history, then try appending `> errorlog 2>&1` to redirect all output (standard and error) to a file `errorlog`.

Comment: Indeed, there is a huge number of lines before the error message I just added to the question.

Comment: Based on that, it looks like you have the project installed on the `C:` drive.  WSL can run into several issues when trying to do Linux operations on files through the 9P protocol driver used for Windows drive access.  Try creating the project under something like `/home/Nobu/src/DRF_Tutos` instead.  I have a feeling it will work then.  It's possible to tell WSL to handle permissions on `C:` through the use of `/etc/wsl.conf`, but if anything in the project is using `inotify`, it just won't work on the `C:` drive through WSL. If moving it works, I'll convert this to an answer with some links.

Comment: I'm currently testing your suggestion, thanks. But in that case, it should work when I try on windows command line, no ?

Comment: It should - Does the `npm --install ...` also error out there?

Comment: Yes, it gives a similar error.

Comment: So I created a new vue project in `/home/Nobu/src/test` folder, I navigated to the good folder and then I launched the `npm run serve` command which resulted in a similar huge error message infortunately.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking on that and sorry it didn't help.  I'll noodle on it some more.  Can you link to the tutorial files you are using?  I'll attempt to reproduce.

Comment: What do you mean by the tutorial files I'm using ? Also I found something interesting: when I create a vue project with `vue create project` and select the default setting and not the manual one, I can then launch the command `npm run serve` without encountering the above mentioned problem. So it seems that the problem is coming from the options selected during the manual setting (router, babel, CSS property etc.). Anyway thank you for your time @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: So good to hear you got it working.  Regarding "tutorials", I made an assumption that `DRF_Tutos` was short for "tutorials", so I figured I would try to reproduce using the same files/tutorial.  Make sure to post your answer and self-accept (even if you don't have the details on *what* in the config broke it) so that the question gets closed out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution to my problem infortunately, but I have a trail (like mentioned in the comments of the question):
when I create a vue project with `vue create project` and select the default setting and not the manual one, I can then launch the command `npm run serve` without encountering the above mentioned problem. So it seems that the problem is coming from the options selected during the manual setting (router, babel, CSS property etc.).